# Can't have same view name?

Tags: orchardcms

I have two custom modules (module1, module2) and I have a page/view with the same name (view1) in both the modules. If I access view1 in module2, I see view1 from module1.

It works if I rename the files or if disable module1.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug with Orchard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, templates can be overridden, so the system needs to be able to find them in lots of different places, by name. Does one of your modules depend on the other? If not, this should not happen. If yes, the system thinks your module1 view is an override for the one in module2. Give your views unique names that contain the module name, or remove the dependency.
Also, you can put your views under a folder that has the name of your controller (which should be easy to make expressive and unique). For example if your controller is ProductAdminController, you can put your views under Views/ProductAdmin/actionname.cshtml